# Install packages to Python2.6

Tags: python, centos

I've just installed Python2.6 on CentOS 5. I have to type python26 to run it. If I type  python I get the default Python 2.4.

Now I need to build a package using python2.6, but it fails because it can't find python-devel. I know python-devel is installed for Python 2.4. How do I install python-devel (or other packages) specifically for Python 2.6?

**EDIT**

I know on WebFaction they have easy_install2.6 to do this type of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python-devel` won't help you, since it will only be available for 2.4. You will need to install the package from source with the appropriate version of Python, e.g. `python2.6 setup.py install`.

Comment: setup.py requires python-devel

Comment: @Yoichi: No, it requires the Python development files. `python-devel` will only contain the development files for the system Python.

Comment: When I ran "python26 setup.py install" from a new package for the first time, it warned me that it required python-devel. After installing python26-devel, the setup.py ran perfectly fine. It needed header files in the python26-devel to compile and link.

Comment: @Yoichi: Have you noticed how that's not `python-devel`?

Answer (score 0):

You can install a specific version of the package, such as:

> yum install python-devel-2.6.2-5.el6.i686

I don't know the exact package version, depends on your CentOS version.

Comment: I'm running CentOS 5. The above didn't work, but thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper - these are tools that help you to install and maintain different versions of python on the save machine. Works fine.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv
http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/

sory, i can't post links yet

Comment: I thought virtualenv used the same version of Python, but ley you keep different packages / versions of packages in the virtualenv?

Comment: not exactly: virtualenv is just a tool that lets you say: I want to use python (and its libs) from that directory. Actualy, that's all it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `~/.bash_profile` and add your local python26 install at the start of the PATH.

If you want proper instructions, write the output of `which python` and tell me the location of your python26 install.

My `.bash_profile` looks like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin/python":/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
unset USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install python26-devel by:

```
sudo yum install python26-devel.x86_64
```